# How to get minio-server version in docker?

Tags: docker, ubuntu-16.04, minio

By using **minio** server in **docker**, i installed and started using it before couple of months ago, now i need to know what version of minio server i am using.

Also want to know how to update existing minio server to latest version, without losing my data?

here: **Ubuntu** version is 16.04 and docker version is 1.13.0.

Answer (score 5):

To show version use:

```
docker run minio/minio version
```

**EDIT 2020:**
To show version use:

```
docker run minio/minio --version
```

To get latest image of minio, use:

```
docker pull minio/minio
```

When it comes to volumes and data it depends on how you stared container

If

```
docker run -d -p 9000:9000 -v /my/local/path:/export minio/minio server /export
```

so you have data in you local (host) path /my local/path

And you can do with container whatever you want

If not I'm not sure whether docker pull destroy your data or not. So I recommend you to copy data from container

```
docker cp [OPTIONS] CONTAINER:SRC_PATH DEST_PATH|-
```

before you do get started.

Comment: Yes it is working, but `docker run minio/minio version` this command create new docker container every time it runs, I dont need this, actually my minio is running on production, i dont want to make experiment there,

Comment: You can run `docker run --rm minio/minio version` it would delete the exited container.

Comment: As of 2020, it seems that `docker run minio/minio version` should be replaced with `docker run minio/minio --version` otherwise you get an error message: _'version' is not a minio sub-command._

Comment: @maxime.bochon you're right, now `docker run minio/minio --version` works

Answer (score 1):

find the docker container name with

```
sudo docker ps
```

then you can

```
sudo docker inspect <container name> | grep "version"
```

or

```
sudo docker exec -it <container name> minio --version
```

It doesn't create a new container this way.

Answer (score 0):

If you have configured `mc` to talk to docker, you can just:

```
mc admin info <target>
```

And you’ll get the version (along with other information).